# using zipinfo and zipfile in python

Tags: python, zip

I want to know the difference between using

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile('zippedfile.zip')

txt = z.getinfo(filename).comment.decode('utf-8')
```

and

```
txt = zipinfo(filename).comment.decode('utf-8')
```

they don't give me the same result, despite it suppose to "as i understand from the documentation"

Comment: What even is `zipinfo`? I can't find anything with that name in the stdlib or on pypi.

Comment: @Aran-Fey `zipfile.ZipInfo` in stdlib

Answer (score -1):

You're not supposed to create `ZipInfo` objects manually; they're automatically constructed by `ZipFile` in order to represent each file in the archive.

`ZipInfo` doesn't know how to extract a file from a `.zip` - that's what `ZipFile` does. (Even if `ZipInfo` could extract a file, how would it know which `.zip` the filename you provided belongs to?)

Comment: I'm not using zopinfo to extract file in this case. I just want to get the comments associated to the files in the zipped folder

Comment: extract file, get associated comments, the exact operation doesn't matter. The answer still applies.